# Pillow - Efficiently write texts to multiple images and then convert them into PDF

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

this is my first stackoverflow question.

I would like to write some texts into two A4 size images, and then convert those images into a 2 pages PDF in a loop.
Just yesterday, I got in touch with Python Pillow and succesfully add texts to images and saved it to disk. I was thinking to save me a Disk Read/Write by doing the images in the memory and only save it to disk after PDF conversion. How can I achieve it in Python?

I had created 2 function for the image creation and had it created two different image files. I can convert thus files to PDF but that will include multiple write, read and deleting the files which I think isn't quite efficient. I'm looking to do it in the memory and save it only after PDF conversion. Thus, It will speed up the process of generating PDFs.

Thanks

Comment: Please click [edit] and add a [mcve] along with the error messages it produces - then folks can help you better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a PDF directly with PIL. First make a list of pages, each one containing a `PIL Image`, then write them all:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Set dimensions
h, w = 3000, 2400

# Make list of pages, add as many as you like
pages = []
pages.append(Image.new('RGB', (w, h), 'red'))
pages.append(Image.new('RGB', (w, h), 'blue'))

# Save as PDF, and set some fields for extra fun
pages[0].save('result.pdf', save_all=True, append_images=pages[1:], title="Friendly Title", author="Mark", subject="Friendly Subject")
```

The result looks like this on a Mac:

[image]

Comment: I'm using 2 functions to draw texts on 2 different images without saving it to disk, but I got a "cannot save mode RGBA"  everytime. I did give it white background before adding the texts but it still produce the same error.